Direction of impulse
My textbook has the following problem:

A batsman deflects a ball by an angle of 45° without changing the initial speed which is equal to 54 km/h. What is the impulse imparted to the ball? (Mass of the ball is 0.15 kg)

I approached this problem by calculating the impulse separately along the horizontal and vertical directions, and then took the square root of the sum of the squares of each of them to find the magnitude.
However, the textbook solution says something different:

Impulse is directed along the bisector of the initial and final directions. Its magnitude is 0.15 ·  2 · 15 · cos(22.5°) = 4.2 kg·m·s⁻¹

How is the impulse directed along the bisector, and how have they done the calculation for the magnitude? It seems like they've failed to explain this.

I do realize that both of the approaches are equivalent because their answer's the same as mine.

Do you really think that the component of momentum in the direction tangent to the wall changes?

Let's start by asking what is impulse ?
Its the change in momentum of the body under consideration i.e.
$$\vec{I}=\Delta \vec{p} = \vec{p}_{final}-\vec{p}_{initial}$$
Now , say that the ball's initial velocity $\vec{v}_i$ , is parallel to the ground and after the hit it got deflected by $45°$ (actually the deflection given should be $135°$ for getting correct answer) making the final velocity to be $\vec{v}_f$. Also ,
$$|\vec{v}_i|=|\vec{v}_f|=54 km/h=15m/s$$
$$m=0.15kg$$
The situation is shown below:
Clearly, the momentum vectors are also along the velocity vectors scaled by the mass of the ball.
So , let's calculate the impulse:
$$\vec{I}=\vec{p}_{final}-\vec{p}_{initial}=\vec{p}_{final}+(-\vec{p}_{initial}) $$
$$\vec{I}=m[\vec{v}_{f}+(-\vec{v}_{i})]\tag{1}$$
So we have add $\vec{v}_f$ with negative of $\vec{v}_i$.The vector diagram is:
Where , $\vec{v}_R$ represents the resultant vector , whose magnitude is given by :
$$|\vec{v}_R|=\sqrt{v_i^2+v_f^2+2v_i v_fcos(45°)}\tag{2}$$
Where, $v_i$ represent the magnitude of $\vec{v}_i$.

How is the impulse directed along the bisector

From the vector diagram above it should be clear that the resultant lies along the bisector of the angle between the two , since both the vectors have same magnitude.

how have they done the calculation for the magnitude

From eq$(1)$ and $(2)$ , and since $v_i=v_f= 15m/s$ , we get:
$$\vec{I}=m(\vec{v}_R)$$
$$|\vec{I}|=I=mv_R=m\sqrt{2v_i^2+2v_i^2cos(45°)}$$
$$I=\sqrt{2}mv_i\sqrt{1+cos(45°)}=\sqrt{2}mv_i\sqrt{2cos^2(\frac{45}{2}) }$$
The above identity is :$1+cos(\theta)=2cos^2(\frac{\theta}{2})$
Hence , the required magnitude is :
$$I=2mv_icos(\frac{45}{2})$$

Impulse is just the change in momentum, which is the difference between the final momentum vector and initial momentum vector. If these two vectors are of the same magnitude, then their difference will be an equal angle between the two vectors.

Why the Impulse is Along the Bisector:

The ball's speed doesn't change, only its direction.
This means the magnitude of momentum remains constant, but its
direction changes.
The change in momentum (and thus the impulse) is the vector
difference between the final and initial momentum.
Geometrically, this vector difference bisects the angle between the
initial and final directions.



Since impulse is the difference between two vectors, it will always be along the diagonal of a parallelogram formed by the initial and final momentum-regardless of if there is a change in speed or not. Check for yourself in the picture. Clearly using tip-to-tail we have $$m\vec{v}_0 +\Delta \vec{p} = m\vec{v}_f \rightarrow \Delta \vec{p} = m\vec{v}_f-m\vec{v}_0$$
In the case of no change in speed, the picture just simplifies to a more symmetric parallelogram (rhombus).


The approach that you have used and the approach they hav used are absurdly close but not exactly same.(∆P~0.02)
And the impulse is directed along the bisector in this case as the particle has deflected with the same initial velocity.
Also you cannot directly take square root of the sum of the squares  of initial and final momentum.(Violating law of VA), also it'd be the impulse as if the particle deflected normally
In order to calculate what you've asked change in momentum, it'd be (mvcosx) -(-mvcosx) resulting
2mvcosx, where x is simply angle between initial velocity and the surface of the bat
(total deflection/2) i.e. 22.5°
